# Dimension of a subset of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, affine-geometry

I'm currently reading *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* by David C. Lay. Chapter 8 section 1 defines the *dimension of a set S* (in this context $S$ is understood to be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$) as the *dimension of the smallest flat containing $S$*.

I want to know why this definition is at all useful because wouldn't it imply that a straight line has dimension $1$, but a curve in $\mathbb R^3$ that twists and turns has dimension $3$?

Intuitively, I would say that both of those objects are $1$ dimensional, so why does he define dimension like this?

Comment: You are correct, this is just good when studying linear algebra, linear subspaces, flats, etc. For objects like curve there should be different notions of dimension, from differential geometry, topology, algebraic geometry, etc. So the definition you talk about is just a convenient shorthand: dimension(S) = dimension of flat generated by S, because in linear algebra you like to talk about linear subspaces/flats generated by subsets.

Comment: And, it is not very standard shorthand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am unfamiliar with the definition, It makes sense to define dimension like this because it would take at least 3 vectors to span the curve. In other contexts, you would be right, the curve can be said to be a 1 dimensional manifold, that is, each point on the curve is locally "homeomorphic"(i.e. looks like) a line.